# JqGrid - virtual scrolling demo not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid to reflect contents of a table in the DB.
This table may have 1,000,000 records - and I wanted to use virtual scrolling.

So firstly, I tried using the demo

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html > New in version 3.7 > Virtual scrolling

I use the demo as is (and complemented the data needed).

However, it doesn't work as expected!!!

First, in the html part there are rowNum: 50 and rowTotal: 2000
but the server receives these two parameters in a GET request: rows=2000 totalrows=2000
and consequently, calculates there is only 1 page.

So I tried in the PHP code - ignore the request and act as if rows=50, however only 50 records are shown and when I scroll down, nothing happens, and the grid shows there are only 50 records total.

I also tried removing rowTotal from the HTML part, but that just led again to displaying only 50 records.

No matter what I tried, there is no real virtual scrolling - there is only one request towards the server.

By the way, I am using jqgrid - 4.5.4 with jquery 1.11.0.
Thanks for any help you may have to offer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the demo:

the demo has
loadonce:true

but clearly it should be 
loadonce:false